# Probability of heads using induction

Tags: probability, induction, binomial-distribution

I am stumped on a problem:

> A coin with $p${h} = $p = 1-q$ is tossed n times. Show that the probability that the number of heads is even equals $0.5[1+(q-p)^n]$.

From the assumption, we know that is coin is an unfair coin with different probabilities for heads and tails (otherwise $p-q$ would always be zero). I figured the best way to show this would be through induction, but so far I'm stumped when it comes to the $(n+1)$ case.

It is trivial to show that when $n=1$ we get $p${even} = $q$. So, with that step is taken care of we assume true for $n$ and prove $n+1$. However, I'm not sure what to do when I get to the $(n+1)^{th}$ step. That is:

$$0.5[1+(q-p)^{n+1}]$$

Thank you in advanced for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: In $n+1$ flips, it will have an even number of heads iff one of the following two things are true:  in the first $n$ flips, there are an even number of heads and the $n+1$'st flip is a tails  **or** in the first $n$ flips there are an *odd* number of heads and the $n+1$'st flip is a head.

Comment: Also, "*we know that the coin is an unfair coin with different probabilities... otherwise $p-q$ would be zero*"  The point is that it doesn't *matter* if $p$ and $q$ are different.  The claim holds in the case that $p=q$ as well as in the case that $p\neq q$.  Regardless, knowledge of whether $p=q$ or $p\neq q$ is irrelevant to the proof.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I think your pointing out I can translate that into the formula, but I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Okay, I do understand that second part. But I guess if $p=q$ would it be worth modeling it this way?

Comment: Are you familiar with the multiplication principle of probability?  $Pr(E\cap F)= Pr(E)\cdot Pr(F\mid E)$.  In this case, let the experiment be flipping the coin $n+1$ number of times.  Let $E$ be the event that you flip heads an even number of times in the first $n$ flips.  Let $F$ be the event that the $n+1$'st flip is tails.  What does the event $E\cap F$ represent?  What is $Pr(F\mid E)$ (*is $F$ independent from $E$?*)?  What is $Pr(E)$ (*by induction*)?  What then is $Pr(E\cap F)$?  What else do you need to calculate still in order to find $Pr(\text{even number of heads in n+1 flips})$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Let $r_{n}$ denote the probability that by $n$ tosses the number
of heads is even.

Then: $$r_{0}=1$$ and: $$r_{n+1}=qr_{n}+p\left(1-r_{n}\right)$$

Based on these equations by induction you can prove that: $$r_{n}=\frac{1}{2}\left[1+\left(q-p\right)^{n}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using induction, but this still gives you the desired solution:

$P_{2k}$ = probability of the number of heads being even

$X_{i}$ = event of 2i even tosses, $i = 1,2,3...$

The set of of the number of heads being even is

$$
\{2k\ heads\} = X_{0} \cup X_{1} \cup ... X_{k}
$$
                The probability of 2i even tosses is
            $$
   P(X_{i}) = \binom{n}{2i}p^{2i}q^{n-2i}
   $$
                So the total probability of all events with even number of heads is
            $$
   P_{2k} = P(\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{k} X_{i}) = \sum_{i=0}^{i=k}P(X_{i}) = \sum_{i=0}^{i=k}\binom{n}{2i}p^{2i}q^{n-2i}
   $$
                What we got in the right side is all the binomial coefficients with p to an even power. That is the result of
            $$
   \sum_{i=0}^{i=k}\binom{n}{2i}p^{2i}q^{n-2i} = \dfrac{1}{2}[ \sum_{i=0}^{i=k}\binom{n}{i}p^{i}q^{n-i} + \sum_{i=0}^{i=k}(-1)^{i}\binom{n}{i}p^{i}q^{n-i}]
   $$
We divide by two to remove the overcount on the even coefficients. Now what is between the brackets is the binomial decomposition of $(q+p)^n$ and $(q-p)^n$

$$
P_{2k} = \dfrac{1}{2}[(q+p)^n + (q-p)^n]
$$
But $q+p = 1$, so we get the desired result:
$$
P_{2k} = \dfrac{1}{2}[1 + (q-p)^n]
$$